# Access dynamically a JSONObject without the key

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSONObject of parameters in this form:

```
{"WOOD":6,"QUARTZ":11};
```

I would like to simply test that the first field is "WOOD", the second is "6" etc.

Doing this
        `parameters.get((String)parameters.keys().next());`
returns 6, I cannot understand why it does not return "WOOD".

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first" field in a JSON object. Fields are not ordered. You're getting the value associated to the first key, and this value is 6. parameters.keys().next() is the "first" key.

Comment: is it possible to determine an order to the keys?

Comment: Maybe your JSON parser respects it. Maybe it doesn't. But you should not rely on it because it's not meaningful, and the generator on the other end might change it. Why do you care about the order of the keys?

Comment: so that i choose which one is the first, so that parameters.keys().next() returns it

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. But if the order matters, then use an array, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keys()` method to get all the keys (it returns an `iterator`) and `iterate` through it to get the values, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject("{\"WOOD\":6,\"QUARTZ\":11}");
    Iterator keys = object.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        Object key = keys.next();
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(object.get(key.toString()));
    }
}
```